# socket.io terminating on second http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a little node.js app that uses subdomains to shorten links which are submitted in the site's path (i.e. requesting `http://a.example.com/google.com` makes it so `a.example.com` redirects to `google.com` in the future).

I wanted to use socket.io to make it so the subdomain was parked only as long as a user had the redirection page (`store.html`) open. Using the open connection, I could also send the user a notification that the page was accessed by someone else, etc.  I am tracking the status of this `store.html` connection by watching for the socket.io disconnection event.

server:

```
var app = require('express')()
, fs = require ('fs')
, http = require('http').createServer(app)
, io = require('socket.io')(http)
, links = {};

app.get('/favicon.ico',function(r,s){});
app.get('/',function(req,res) {
  var subd=req.subdomains[0];
  if (!subd) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
  } else {
    if (link[subd]) {
      res.redirect(link[subd].URL);
    } else {
      res.send('nothing saved here');
    }
  }
});
app.get('*',function(req,res) {
  var subd=req.subdomains[0];
  if (!subd) {
    res.send('invalid URL');
  } else  if (link[subd]) {
    res.send('subdomain in use');
  } else {
    var URL=req.originalUrl.substring(1);
    link[subd]={ URL: (/^\w+:\/\//.test(URL) ? URL : (/^\w+\.\w+/.test(URL) ?  http://'+URL : 'http://google.com')) };
    res.sendfile(__dirname+'/public/store.html');
  }
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('subd',function(subd) {
    socket.subd=subd;
    link[subd].socket=socket;
    socket.emit('content',link[subd].URL);
  });
  socket.on('disconnect',function() {
    delete link[socket.subd];
  });
});
```

store.html:

```
<html>
<body>
  <span>HTML / Link</span>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    var subd=location.hostname.split('.').shift()'
    var socket = io.connect('http://example.com');
    socket.on('connect', function() {
      socket.emit('subd', subd);
    });
    socket.on('content',function(content) {
      document.getElementById('content').innerHTML='<a href="'+content+'">'+content+'</a>';
    });
    socket.on('disconnect',function(reason){
      alert(reason);
    });
   </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The problem I'm running into is that if I connect to the subdomain within the same browser, I get a "transport error" and disconnection event, closing the socket and triggering the deletion of the subdomain from the `link` object.  How can I keep the socket open when I access the same page in a new tab? How are the two linked?

restated, this is how the problem happens:

1. visit `http://link.example.com/google.com`
2. visit `link.example.com` , redirects to google
3. socket closes unexpectedly
4. visit `link.example.com`, receive response indicating emptiness

Comment: When you connect to the subdomain within the same browser, are you navigating away from, or refreshing store.html? I think if you do either, you'll disconnect from the socket.

Comment: @Houseman no, connecting in a new tab. i'm leaving store.html open and starting a new connection